# Using class.forname().newInstance() and "com.sun.jdi.InvocationException occurred invoking method" exception

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, introspection

I am using class.forname to create a new instance of class.The classname comes from a properties.

Lets say i have several classes in two packages.

```
com.package.Parser1
com.package.Parser2
com.package.Parser3

net.package.parser4
net.package.parser5
net.package.parser6
```

The following classes also exist in the above packages (This are not instantiated)

```
com.package.ParserLoader
com.package.ParserInterface
net.package.GenericParser
```

On initialisation, the above parser are put in a vector. The vector is then accessed and each class is initialised using its class name as shown below

```
while (tokens.hasMoreTokens())

        parsers.addElement(

            Class.forName((String) tokens.nextToken()).newInstance());
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The code above is in the class ParserLoader which is in the same package as parsers 1,2,3.

Parsers 1, 2 and 3 all implement the ParserInterface. 
Parsers 4,5 and 6 all extends the abtract GenericParser. 
The GenericParser implements the ParserInterface.

When i run the above it generates an exception shown below

```
com.sun.jdi.InvocationException occurred invoking method
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

### Edit

Another problem i am having is i cant see any stack trace. There is no stacktrace! I only see that error in eclipse when i debug the application and look at the content of the parsers vector. The vector should contain references to the parser objects. The parsers in com.package.* package are fine but it is not creating instances of any parser in the net.package.* package.

Comment: Please post the complete stacktrace.

Comment: Thats another problem i am having. There is no stacktrace! I only see that error in eclipse when i debug it and look at the content of the parsers vector. This should contain references for the parser objects. The parsers in com.package.* package are fine but it is not creating instances of any parser in the net.package.* package.

Comment: That exception is from the debugging interface. (Probably a problem with the interfacing to your debugger, so I've added the eclipse tag.)

Comment: What does that mean? Do you mean its not an exception with the application but with the eclipse IDE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll get this exception if your constructors are messed up or something else is broken while creating the parsers. Check this out: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jdk/api/jpda/jdi/com/sun/jdi/InvocationException.html, and try to get more info out of your exception.

Answer (score 1):

`com.package.ParserInterface` sounds like a interface, and you are not able to create an instance from an interface.

Comment: No its doesnt instantiate the interface. See the edit. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting `com.sun.jdi.InvocationException` in the `value` column of the `Variables` tab of the debug pane, it is most likely that your `Preferences-Java-Debug-Detail` Formatters are set to display `toString()` for the values of variables.

If the object is not fully built yet, but `toString()` calls a method with not yet available data, an invocation exception is expected and helpful.

To see a nicer but a redundant text, check the `In detail pane only` option (or whatever is relevant to your version of Eclipse).